# htaccess search query redirect/rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to figure out how to change the way my browser interprets the follow URI:

example.com/pages/search.php?category=work_flow

into:

example.com/search/category=work_flow

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/search/?$ /pages/search.php [L]
```

But it doesn't work. I don't have much experience with Htaccess so I would appreciate an explantation as well.

Thank you

Edit: My question didn't seem to be clear enough

Comment: There's rarely a reason to rewrite search urls. Users don't care, and Googlebot will ignore it anyway. But see also: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want is this way?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Example 1: detail search page
RewriteRule ^search$ /pages/search.php [NC,L,QSA]

# Example 2 - search with in the category: example.com/search/category
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /pages/search.php?type=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Example 3: example.com/search/category/work_flow
# or example.com/search/user/work_flow
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)$ /pages/search.php?type=$1&work=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```